# how to apply same animation in up direction when clicking on same div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery code which works fine. When I click on the wrapper the first time, it will fold on itself from top to bottom. What I want is for the same animation to repeat again when I click on wrapper but upwards, i.e. from bottom to top . my all code is as below

> JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#Wrapper').data('showing', false).click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    var elems = ["#Article_1", "#fold12", "#fold123"];
    // if showing, reverse the display order
    if($this.data('showing')) {
        elems.reverse();

    }

    // reverse the flag
    $this.data('showing', !$this.data('showing'));

    // loop elements and apply toggle
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.toggleClass('magictime perspectiveDown'); 
        }.bind($(elems[i])), (i + 1) * 1000);
        }

    });
});
```

> HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Two Column Layout</TITLE>
<script 
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://minimamente.com/example/magic_animations/css/magic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </script>
              <script src="jquery.js"></script>
              <script src="dist/animatecss.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
                 </HEAD>
<BODY>
    <SECTION ID="Wrapper">
 <div id="fold123">
     <div id="fold12">
        <ARTICLE ID="Article_1">
            <HEADER ID="Header_Article_1">
                <H2>Article One Title</H2>
            </HEADER>
            <SECTION ID="Section_Article_1">
                <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
            </SECTION>
        </ARTICLE>
        <ARTICLE ID="Article_2">
            <HEADER ID="Header_Article_2">
                <H2>Article Two Title</H2>
            </HEADER>
            <SECTION ID="Section_Article_2">
                <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
            </SECTION>
                                            </ARTICLE>
                               </div>
        <ARTICLE ID="Article_3">
            <HEADER ID="Header_Article_3">
                <H2>Article Three Title</H2>
            </HEADER>
            <SECTION ID="Section_Article_3">
                <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
            </SECTION>
        </ARTICLE>
                                        </div>
                                           <ARTICLE ID="Article_4">
            <HEADER ID="Header_Article_4">
                <H2>Article Four Title</H2>
            </HEADER>
            <SECTION ID="Section_Article_4">
                <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
            </SECTION>
        </ARTICLE>
    </SECTION>
    <FOOTER>
        <P>Your footer content here</P>
    </FOOTER>
  </BODY>
</HTML
```

I am using https://github.com/miniMAC/magic

How do I do that? Any Suggestions improving animation are also appreciated.

Comment: provide link to that fiddle

Comment: Please don't try to get round the code warning message by not linking to the Fiddle, the relevant code needs to be in the question itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HtTXB/19/

Comment: Please see the above fiddle. ..I have provided in comment box above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reverse it using "magic".

The reason is that all the animations are affect on the element which not yet animated. The thing that you tiring to do, is to animate element which is animated already and something like this not supported in the "magic" framework.

I think you need to do it yourself.

**Something like this:** (you can improve this code as you want, but this is the general way)

```js
$('.wrapper').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('expand');
});
```

```css
header {
  background:#DCDCDC;
  padding: 20px 5px;
}

section {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  background:#F8EBEB;
}

div {
  width:400px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0);
}

.expand div:not(:last-child) {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-180deg);
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay:3s;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay:2s;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay:1s;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay:0s;
}

.expand div:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay:0s;
}
.expand div:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay:1s;
}
.expand div:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay:2s;
}
.expand div:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay:3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <header>Article 1 Title</header>
    <section>The contents of this section go here.</section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <header>Article 2 Title</header>
    <section>The contents of this section go here.</section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <header>Article 3 Title</header>
    <section>The contents of this section go here.</section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <header>Article 4 Title</header>
    <section>The contents of this section go here.</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and effort that's a great solution.